# How can I stop an overlay from inheriting the properties of underlying text?

Tags: faces, overlays

I'm using an overlay to display additional information next to Dired candidates, because modifying the Dired buffer directly prevents Dired from working properly. I'm displaying the text using a `propertize`d string in the `before-string` property of the overlay.

I've given the string a face. The problem is, it inherits properties from the underlying text when they are unspecified in the face. For example, let's say Dired is displaying a file with a strikethrough. If the overlay is placed at the start of that file, the overlay will display the `before-string` with a strikethrough.

Here is the code for creating a dummy overlay:

```el
(let ((current-overlay (make-overlay (point) (point)))
                  (info-string (propertize "[dummy info]"
                                            'face 'my-dired-numbers-face)))
              (overlay-put current-overlay 'before-string info-string))
```

The whole function is as follows:

```el
(defface my-dired-numbers-face
  '((t :inherit 'font-lock-keyword-face
       :weight bold :background nil :strike-through nil))
  "The face used to display selection numbers to the user.")

(defun my-dired-insert-numbers (&rest _)
  (if my-dired-number-overlays
      (mapc (lambda (overlay)
              (delete-overlay overlay))
            my-dired-number-overlays))
  (setq my-dired-number-overlays '())
  (save-excursion
    (let ((n 1)
          (old-point (point))
          (end-of-buffer 0))
      (goto-char 0)
      (while (= end-of-buffer 0)
        (if (dired-move-to-filename)
            (let ((current-overlay (make-overlay (point) (point)))
                  (number-string (propertize (my-dired-format-string (number-to-string n) 3)
                                             'face 'my-dired-numbers-face)))
              (overlay-put current-overlay 'after-string number-string)
              (setq n (1+ n))
              (push current-overlay my-dired-number-overlays)))
        (setq end-of-buffer (forward-line))))))
```

Does anyone know how to override this behaviour? Can I get my `before-string` to display without inheriting any properties?

---

**Edit:** I've managed to get around this problem by passing `default` as the lowest-priority face to `propertize`. This explicitly sets all undefined properties to those of the `default` face (overriding the inherited properties). This is the relevant line:

```el
(number-string (propertize (my-dired-format-string "[dummy string]"
                            'face '(my-dired-numbers-face
                                    default)
```

This seems like a hacky solution though. Is there an intended way to do this?

Comment: You want to look at the `priority` property for overlays.  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlay-Properties.html  Negative `priority` are not officially supported, but they work in some circumstances and I use them as needed.  In addition, "*. . . all overlays take priority over text properties.*"  If you want to trump something, just set your overlay `priority` higher than others that are present at the same location, or set the others to lower values.  To do this properly, you should look into what `priority` values are set for other overlays that are present.

Comment: I've got a function that prints all overlays on a specific line and it isn't detecting any overlays except for my own. The problem is that it's inheriting the text-properties from the underlying text.

Comment: Place your cursor at wherever the problem is, and type `C-u C-x =`.  The help buffer will show everything that is present.  The manual states that "**. . . all overlays take priority over text properties.**"  So, it would theoretically be impossible for your overlays to inherit text properties.

Comment: `C-u C-x =` confirms that there are no overlays other than my own. It's inheriting the underlying text properties and does so for each property until I explicitly designate a new, non-nil value.

Comment: Would it help any to define `my-dired-numbers-face` to have all elements desired, instead of inheriting `font-lock-keyword-face` -- i.e., expressly define all elements of possible face attributes?

Comment: I considered it. I switch themes a lot, so I need to inherit to ensure consistency between them. I'll also probably be doing other stuff with overlays in the future so I'd like to know if there's a general solution.